# Using declaration in template derived class not recognized by g++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The following code fails to compile with g++ 4.9, 5.4, and 6.2.

```
template <class T, int M, int N>
struct Matrix { };

template <typename T> struct Traits;
class Derived;

template <>
struct Traits<Derived>
{
  static constexpr int N= 3;
};

template <typename T>
class Base: public Traits<T>
{
protected:
  using Traits<T>::N;
  static const Matrix<double,N,N> Mat;
};

template <typename T>
const Matrix<double,Base<T>::N,Base<T>::N> Base<T>::Mat;

class Derived: public Base<Derived> {};

int main()
{
Derived foo;
}
```

I get the error message `‘const Matrix<double, #‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>, #‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>, (AutoAlign | (((#‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error> == 1) && (#‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error> != 1)) ? RowMajor : (((#‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error> == 1) && (#‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error> != 1)) ? ColMajor :  ColMajor))), #‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>, #‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error> > Base<T>::Mat`.

I don't understand what is wrong. Could somebody help?

A workaround consist of:

```
template <typename T>
class Base: public Traits<T>
{
protected:
  static constexpr auto N= Traits<T>::N;
  static const Matrix<double,N,N> Mat;
};
```

Comment: I believe part of what you're seeing is simply the error reporter not being able to create the message for the error.  that's the "#‘using_decl’ not supported by dump_expr#" part

Comment: I confirm the problem with clang++ 3.5: the error is "redefinition of 'Mat' with a different type: 'const Matrix<[...], Base<T>::N, Base<T>::N>' vs 'const Matrix<[...], N, N>'"

Comment: The problem is one of dependent names, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  The compiler doesn't know they're the same.  I think it involves throwing "template" in some more places, but I'm not sure whree.